# Performing a series of SQL queries, and need to be able to cancel them from the main UI thread. What is the best approach?

Tags: multithreading, ado.net, backgroundworker, sqlclient

Currently, I have several queries that need to run in order (some create temp tables which I draw from in later queries).

The queries run in a `BackgroundWorker` thread, and currently if there is a `CancellationPending`, I break out of the method in between query calls.

However this approach is problematic as there are times when a single query can run for a long time or never returns, so I need to be able to run each query while polling for `BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending`.

What is the best asynchronous pattern to use in this case? I need to fill a `DataTable` for each query, but still have the ability to cancel if it takes too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all cases, abort cooperatively. Don't even think about using `Thread.Abort`.

[The great Stephen Toub has written a best-practice.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/11/10/10235834.aspx)

TL;DR: When a timeout timer fires you complete the `Task` immediately and let the SQL query continue to run. You just ignore it.

Comment: Finally got around to using async/await with ADO.NET. Code is simple and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: The solution that ended up working for me was to use the asynchronous ADO.NET methods. `BeginExecute...` and `EndExecute...`

Here is a snippet of code that asynchronously performs a query while checking whether a `BackgroundWorker` has requested cancellation. The function returns true if the query ran to completion, and false if a cancellation was performed.

The code should be called from somewhere within the `BackgroundWorker`'s `DoWork` function.

```cs
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connectionObj);
IAsyncResult result = command.BeginExecuteReader();  // end async execution

// check for user cancellation while result is not complete
while (!result.IsCompleted)
{
    if (myBackgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
    {
        command.Cancel();  // cancel the existing command
        try
        {
             command.EndExecuteReader(result);  // cancel async execution
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            // will always enter here due to command.Cancel()
            // this is expected
        }

        return false;
    }

    Thread.Sleep(100);  // sleep so loop doesn't consume all the resources
}

// result is complete, do something with data
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.EndExecuteReader(result))
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Load(reader);
}

// do something with table
return true;
```